# Should we be able to send private messages to other users?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

On many other forums, they allow you to send private messages to other users. Should this function be added to Stack Overflow too?

Comment: No, because Stack Overflow *isn't* a forum.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

Comment: I think we should really amend that statement to "Stack Overflow is not a message board", since it is so self-evidently a forum that repeatedly denying it to new users is just going to confuse/annoy them.

Comment: Please do explain what you think the advantage of this would be. Why communicate privately with someone when you can post the question/answer on the site for everyone to benefit?

Comment: @Cody Gray, I answered a question on stackoverflow and according to the comments it is the correct answer (even though it isn't the highest voted answer yet), however, the user that asked the question didn't mark any answer as the correct anser yet. I would like to bring it to his attention. I understand the Problem of being able to write privatly but I would like to get his attention somehow.

Comment: To prohibit private messages could be a good decision if user tagging worked fine. It seems it doesn't.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> On many other forums, they allow you to send private messages to other
>   users. Should this function be added to StackOverflow too?

1,000,000% no!

I have watched other tech—and non-tech—communities rise & fall over the years. And it boils down to petit fiefdoms & other political B.S. forming. What usually happens is someone started a website or a blog, then decides, “Hey! Let me install some free forum software, how hard can it be?” And then before you know it all of the classic B.S. happens that destroys communities and alienates others.

In contrast, the way the Stack Exchange sites foster community via transparency is not perfect, but it’s truly better than the in-fighting I have seen from back in the BBS days of the 1980s to the forum fights I have actually seen break out in more modern, private online forums.

The purpose of the Stack Exchange sites is to foster community based on shared, visible and transparent community participation to help poster’s solve issues. The mechanisms in place that allow the quality of posts to be publicly managed and peer reviewed work well.

That said, if an individual user wants to publicly post their email or personal website on their profile, that is their own business. Most people actually won’t take the social “jump” to contacting folks directly like that. So anyone who does do that will have to make a strong effort.

This community is far from perfect, but as far as it being a public resource, I think it’s great. I think of the Stack Exchange sites like the [Usenet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) but with better, more modern controls and capabilities.

Answer (score 16):

I'm going to say no for another reason.  I have some contact info in my profile for business networking purposes.  As it is I get private emails asking me questions, with varying degrees of politeness (from appollogeticly seeking me out as a domain expert to demanding answers).  I can just imagine how bad it would be if SO had built in PMs-  high karma users would be so inundated they'd have to ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need in private messages on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow isn't a forum or social network. It is Q&A. One asks a question, others answer. If you want to communicate with him, send him an email. Why do you want private messages?

Comment: yet chat exists...

Comment: chat is voluntary you never have to set foot in it