# Please rate-limit usage of "start a new room with this user"

Tags: feature-request, chat, rate-limiting, abuse

[Stack Overflow does not have a PM system, because everything is supposed to be about the content, not the user/expert.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261885/103167)

Yet, it is evidently possible to spam direct contact to a large number of top experts, using the "start a new room with this user" function.

The number of rooms owned by this user and all opened in a very short time window is absurd (the information on that page is hidden in mouseover text and links, a screenshot would not suffice): https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/383779/sergiol

Can we please get a rate limit on usage of this feature?

Comment: Why do we even *have* that feature? Why are people allowed to get a room with me without my consent to sharing a room with that person? Thank God it doesn't work that way for hotels and other shared spaces...

Answer (score 32):

This doesn't happen that often, but it is an abuse of the chat system. As a result, I've suspended the chat account of this particular user and warned them about this.

I agree that there should be a rate limit on this, even as rarely as this is abused. In the meantime, if you see this happening, flag down a moderator and we'll act on it.

Comment: Flag where/how?  AFAIK requests to allow voting on flagging on particular user pages are still being declined, and chat flags have to be placed on a chat message -- an empty room doesn't have any messages to be flagged.  I guess I could speak up in the chat room and then flag my own message?

Comment: @BenVoigt - Flag any of their posts on the main site (which they'd have to have in order to be at a rep level to chat) or use a chat flag on one of their posts in chat. The former would be preferred, since chat flags are a little awkward to deal with.

Comment: @BradLarson or just open a room between you and a mod. ;-)