# How to find out if a particular user is online or offline on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I want to know how to find if a user is online or offline on Stack Overflow. If possible how to chat with that particular user on Stack Overflow rather than relying on chat rooms.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261885/should-we-be-able-to-send-private-messages-to-other-users

Comment: i didn't know that . Should i delete my question.

Comment: I think you can't delete because I and others upvoted the answer from Oded. it is fine to leave it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, not directly.

Closest thing to being able to do that is go to a chat room that user has been in recently and try to @ ping them (they might even respond). Note that after a couple of weeks of inactivity, this won't work and that a large number of users never use chat.

We are not a social network, we focus on questions and answers, not people - don't look for social network features here.

Comment: What about finding whether they are online or offline ?

Comment: @Project-A The profile has a "last seen" field that can give some idea but it is deliberately not high precision.